# Vee-validate seems to slow down input typing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

The input field with vee-validation seemed so **slow** to type in or everytime i tab to move to another field. i don't have any idea since i've followed the documentations example, [this one](https://codesandbox.io/s/validation-components-bootstrapvue-usdwv?from-embed)

I'm using vee-validate version **Version 3.x**, **bootstrap-vue**,
and.. there are about **20 input fields** about to validate in a single file.

What could the possible problems that cause this slow down?

```
<template>
    <div fluid class="animated fadeIn">
        <ValidationObserver ref="observer" v-slot="{ passes }">
            <b-form @submit.prevent="passes(kirim)"> 
                <b-card>
                    <b-row align-h="center">
                        <b-col md="12" lg="12">

                            <b-row class="form-group">
                                <b-col md="6" lg="6" offset-md="1">
                                    <ValidationProvider rules="required|numeric" name="telepon_pny" v-slot="{ valid, errors }">
                                        <b-form-group 
                                            label="Telepon Penyewa"
                                            label-cols-sm="4"
                                            label-align-sm="right"
                                        >
                                            <b-input-group size="sm">
                                                <b-form-input type="text" 
                                                :state="errors[0] ? false : (valid ? true : null)"
                                                v-model="tel_pnyw"
                                                ></b-form-input>
                                                    <b-input-group-append><b-input-group-text><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></b-input-group-text></b-input-group-append>
                                                    <b-form-invalid-feedback id="inputLiveFeedback">{{ errors[0] }}</b-form-invalid-feedback>
                                            </b-input-group>
                                        </b-form-group>
                                    </ValidationProvider>
                                </b-col>
                            </b-row>

                            ... //another input field

                            ... //another input field

                            ... //another input field

                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>        
                    <div slot="footer">
                        <b-button size="sm" type="submit" variant="primary" class="btn-ghost-*">Submit</b-button>
                        &nbsp;
                        <b-button size="sm" variant="warning" @click="reset()" class="btn-ghost-*">Reset</b-button>
                    </div>
                </b-card>
            </b-form>
        </ValidationObserver>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        components: {
            ValidationObserver,
            ValidationProvider
        },
        data() {
            return {
                tel_pnyw:'',
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

expected result is there are no lagging issues when i type in an validate activated input field.